# Remove all the punctuation marks but retain full stop in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

```
String abc = "hey. how are you. doing tonight! when we meet?";
abc = abc.replaceAll("[\\p{Punct}&&[^'-]]+", " ");
System.out.println(abc);
```

Output of the above code is:

```
hey  how are you doing tonight  when we meet
```

But i want to retain the full stop so that i can split it to sentence.
Desired output :

```
hey. how are you.  doing tonight when we meet
```

Please help with the regex expression

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex this way :

`abc = abc.replaceAll("[\\p{Punct}&&[^'-.]]+", " ");`

So that `.` will also not be replaced.

O/P :

```
hey. how are you. doing tonight  when we meet
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(\\.)|[\\p{Punct}&&[^'-]]+
```

You can use this replace by `$1` or `\1`.This will capture `.` first and then rest of punctuation characters enabling us to replace rest.